# 100% height in ion-slide-box not working

Tags: css, ionic-framework, slide

I'm using the ion-slide-box in my application. Sometimes the height of the content for a slide is not filling the whole content. This means I have a blank space at the bottom of the slide. In this scenario the user should also be able to slide when he swipes also the blank space at the bottom. However, this is not working since the size of the ion-slide is not 100%. 
I'm also not able to set the size to 100%. I already tried the following:

```
.slider{
  height:100%;
}

.slider-slide {
 height: 100%;
 min-height:100%;
}
```

Using the above code the slide content is still not 100%. Thank you for your help. 
This is the html for the slide-box:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box class="slider" on-slide-changed="slideChanged($index, this)" show-pager="false" active-slide="1" ng-init="handleSlideEnabling()" does-continue="true">
        <ion-slide class="slider-slides" ng-repeat="question in questions">
            <div class="slider-slide">   
            ... some content
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Add your html please.

Comment: I don't see `.slider` nor `.slider-slide` in your html...

Comment: @Chris: Thats because angular directives could be replaced with html later.

Comment: I get that, but the issue is related to css and not Angular in particular. So I'm not interested in pre-rendered markup. I need to see mentioned classes.

Comment: @Chris I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

```
.slider{
  height:100vh;
  width:auto; 
}

.slider-slide {
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: try to explain some more

Comment: This works only if the content is never bigger than the full viewport height. In my slide I have sometimes content which is only reachable when I scroll down. Using 100vh would make this content unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hacky solution, but you can create a custom css container with 100vh to use only on views you know will be less than 100vh.

```
.slider {
  height: 100%;
}
.slide-container {
  height: 100vh;
  // height: calc(100vh - 43px) if you have a header bar that is 43px tall
}
```

Then your html can look like this

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="vm.slideHasChanged($index)">
  <ion-slide>
    <div class="slide-box">
      // Content that is less than 100vh
    </div>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
      // Content that is more than 100vh
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and did not find any good solution to the problem.
So after trying a few things, this is what worked best.

**EDITED:**

My last answer was not very good as it had a annoying behaviour.
It would make all the slides have the same height, therefore making all of them scrollable even when there was no content to scroll in some of them.

So, this is what finally worked best for me.

In my style.css:

```
.slider {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

ion-scroll.custom {
  height: 100vh !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

*The overflow: auto; is beacuse I don't want the scrollbar indicator to be visible all the time.*

The html:

```
<ion-view view-title={{viewTitle}} cache-view="false">

  <ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box show-pager="true" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">

      <ion-slide>
        <ion-scroll class="custom">
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
          <div><h1>FIRST</h1></div>
        </ion-scroll>

      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <ion-scroll class="custom">
          <div><h1>SECOND</h1></div>
        </ion-scroll>

      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <ion-scroll class="custom">
          <div><h1>THIRD</h1></div>
        </ion-scroll>
      </ion-slide>

    </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

Now it respects the content of each slide making the view scrollable only when there's content in overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below css:

```
ion-content .scroll { height: 100%; }
```

worked for me :)